# Prob. 16, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: Some Properties of Riemann Zeta Fucntion

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-zeta

Here is Prob. 16, Chap. 6, in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> For $1 < s < \infty$, define $$ \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}. $$ (This is Riemann's zeta function, of great importance in the study of the distribution of prime numbers.) Prove that
>
> (a) $$  \zeta(s) = s \int_1^\infty \frac{[x]}{x^{s+1} }  \ \mathrm{d} x $$ 
>   and that
>
> (b) $$ \zeta(s) = \frac{s}{s-1} - s \int_1^\infty \frac{x-[x]}{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x.  $$
>   where $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer $\leq x$.
>
> Prove that the integral in (b) converges for all $s > 0$.
>
> *Hint:* To prove (a), compute the difference between the integral over $[1, N]$ and the $N$th partial sum of the series that defines  $\zeta(s)$.

My Attempt:

Here are the links to a couple of relevant posts of mine here on Math SE:

[Prob. 8, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: The Integral Test for Convergence of Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377620/prob-8-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-the-integral-test-for-convergence-of-series)

[Theorem 6.12 (b) in Baby Rudin: If $f_1 \leq f_2$ on $[a, b]$, then $\int_a^b f_1 d\alpha \leq \int_a^b f_2 d\alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327229/theorem-6-12-b-in-baby-rudin-if-f-1-leq-f-2-on-a-b-then-int-ab-f)

[Theorem 6.12 (c) in Baby Rudin: If $f\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$ and $a<c<b$, then $f\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, c]$ and $[c, b]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327286/theorem-6-12-c-in-baby-rudin-if-f-in-mathscrr-alpha-on-a-b-and-a)

[Theorem 6.12 (a) in Baby Rudin: If $f\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$, then $cf\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ for every constant $c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327134/theorem-6-12-a-in-baby-rudin-if-f-in-mathscrr-alpha-on-a-b-then-c)

Prob. 16 (a)

> Let $b$ be a real number such that $b > 2$, and let $N$ be the integer such that $N \leq b < N+1$. Then $N \geq 2$ and we see that 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> s \int_1^b \frac{ [x] }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x &\geq  s \int_1^N \frac{ [x] }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x  \\ 
> &= s \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}  \int_k^{k+1}  \frac{ [x] }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x   \\ 
> &\geq  s \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}  \int_k^{k+1}  \frac{ k }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x   \\ 
> &= s \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} k \int_k^{k+1} x^{-s-1} \ \mathrm{d} x \\
> &= s \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} k \frac{ (k+1)^{-s} - k^{-s} }{ -s } \\
> &= \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} k \left( \frac{ 1 }{ k^s } - \frac{ 1 }{ (k+1)^s } \right). \tag{1}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   On the other hand, 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> s \int_1^b \frac{ [x] }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x  &\leq  s \int_1^{N+1} \frac{ [x] }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x \\
> &= s \sum_{k=1}^{N}  \int_k^{k+1}  \frac{ [x] }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x    \\ 
> &\leq  s \sum_{k=1}^{N}  \int_k^{k+1}  \frac{ k+1 }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x   \\ 
> &= s \sum_{k=1}^{N} (k+1) \int_k^{k+1} x^{-s-1} \ \mathrm{d} x  \\
> &= s \sum_{k=1}^{N} (k+1) \frac{ (k+1)^{-s} - k^{-s} }{ -s } \\
> &= \sum_{k=1}^{N} (k+1) \left( \frac{ 1 }{ k^s } - \frac{ 1 }{ (k+1)^s } \right) \\
> &= \sum_{k=1}^{N} k \left( \frac{ 1 }{ k^s } - \frac{ 1 }{ (k+1)^s } \right)  + \sum_{k=1}^{N}  \left( \frac{ 1 }{ k^s } - \frac{ 1 }{ (k+1)^s } \right)   \\
> &= \sum_{k=1}^{N} k \left( \frac{ 1 }{ k^s } - \frac{ 1 }{ (k+1)^s } \right)  +  \left( 1- \frac{1}{ (N+1)^s } \right). \tag{2} 
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> By combining (1) and (2) we obtain 
>   $$ \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} k \left( \frac{ 1 }{ k^s } - \frac{ 1 }{ (k+1)^s } \right) \leq s \int_1^b \frac{ [x] }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x \leq \sum_{k=1}^{N} k \left( \frac{ 1 }{ k^s } - \frac{ 1 }{ (k+1)^s } \right)  +  \left( 1- \frac{1}{ (N+1)^s } \right)  \tag{3} $$ 
>   for every real number $b > 2$ and for the natural number $N$ such that $N \leq b < N+1$, (i.e.  $N = [b]$) and so $N \geq 2$.
>
> Conversely, for every natural number $N > 2$, we can find a real number $b$ such that $N \leq b < N+1$, and so (3) holds.

Is what I've done so far correct? If so, then how to prove  from here the identity asserted in (a)?

Prob. 16 (b)

> We now assume that 
>   $$ \zeta (s) = s \int_1^\infty \frac{ [ x ] }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x \tag{4} $$
>   holds. Then 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \frac{s}{s-1} - s \int_1^\infty \frac{ x-[x] }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x &= 
> \frac{s}{s-1} - s \int_1^\infty \frac{ 1 }{ x^s } \ \mathrm{d} x + s  \int_1^\infty \frac{ [x] }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x \\
> &= \frac{s}{s-1} - s \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_1^b \frac{ 1 }{ x^s } \ \mathrm{d} x  \ + \ \zeta(s) \qquad \mbox{ [ using (4) ] } \\
> &= \frac{s}{s-1} - s \lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{ b^{-s + 1} - 1  }{ -s+1 } + \zeta (s) \\
> &= \frac{s}{s-1} - s \frac{ \lim_{b \to \infty}  b^{-s + 1} \  - \  1  }{ -s+1 } + \zeta (s) \\
> &= \frac{s}{s-1} - s \frac{ 0  - 1  }{ -s+1 } + \zeta (s) \qquad \mbox{ [ because $s > 1$ ] } \\
> &= \zeta (s), 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   as required.

Am I right?

> Now as $0 \leq x - [x] < 1$ for all real numbers  $x$ and as $x^{s+1} > 0$ for all $x \geq 1$, so 
>   $$ 0 \leq \frac{ x- [x] }{ x^{s+1 } } < \frac{ 1 }{ x^{s+1} }, $$
>   and then we can conclude (from Theorem 6.12 (b) in Rudin ) that 
>   $$ 0 \leq  \int_1^b \frac{ x- [x] }{ x^{s+1 } } \ \mathrm{d} x \leq \int_1^b \frac{ 1 }{ x^{s+1 } } \ \mathrm{d} x $$ 
>   for every real number $b \geq 1$. Therefore, 
>   $$
> \begin{align} 
> 0 \leq  \int_1^\infty \frac{ x-[x] }{x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x  &= \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_1^b \frac{ x-[x] }{x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x \\
> &\leq   \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_1^b \frac{ 1 }{ x^{s+1 } } \ \mathrm{d} x \\
> &= \int_1^\infty \frac{ 1 }{ x^{s+1 } } \ \mathrm{d} x.  \tag{5} 
> \end{align} 
> $$
>   Now the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{ 1 }{ x^{s+1 } } \ \mathrm{d} x$ converges if and only if the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{s+1} }$ converges (by Prob. 8, Chap. 6, in Rudin), since the function $f$ defined on $[1, \infty)$ by
>   $$ f(x) \colon= \frac{1}{x^{s+1} } $$
>   is monotonically decreasing.
>
> Now as $s > 1$, so $ s+1 > 2$ and thus (by Theorem 3.28 in Rudin) the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{s+1}}$ converges. So the last integral in (5) also converges, and then (5) implies the convergence of $ \int_1^\infty \frac{ x-[x] }{x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x  $, as required.

Is what I've asserted so far correct? Have I used the correct and rigorous enough logic in establishing whatever I have?  Or, have I made any mistakes somewhere?

P.S.: After reading the answer and comments below, here is what I've thought of.

Theorem 3.41 in Rudin:

> Given two sequences $\left\{ a_n \right\}$, $\left\{ b_n \right\}$, put 
>   $$ A_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k $$
>   if $n \geq 0$; put $A_{-1} = 0$. Then, if $0 \leq p \leq q$, we have 
>   $$ \sum_{n=p}^q a_n b_n = \sum_{n=p}^{q-1} A_n \left( b_n - b_{n+1} \right) + A_q b_q - A_{p-1} b_p.  \tag{A} $$
>
> So if we put $a_k \colon= 1 = k - (k-1) $ and $b_k \colon= \frac{1}{k^s}$ for $k \geq 1$ and $a_0 = 0$ in (A), then for any integer $r \geq 2$ we obtain 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{k=1}^r \frac{1}{k^s} &= \sum_{k=1}^{r-1} \frac{k - (k-1) }{ k^s }  \\
> &= \sum_{k=1}^{r-1} A_k \left( b_k - b_{k+1} \right) + A_r b_r - A_0 b_1 \\
> &= \sum_{k=1}^{r-1} k \left( \frac{1}{k^s} - \frac{1}{ (k+1)^s } \right) + r \frac{1}{r^s}   \\
> &= \sum_{k=1}^{r-1} k \left( \frac{1}{k^s} - \frac{1}{ (k+1)^s } \right) +  \frac{1}{r^{s-1} },    
> \end{align} 
> $$
>   and so 
>   $$ \sum_{k=1}^{r+1} \frac{1}{k^s}  = \sum_{k=1}^{r} k \left( \frac{1}{k^s} - \frac{1}{ (k+1)^s } \right) +  \frac{1}{ (r+1)^{s-1} },  $$
>   which implies that 
>   $$ \sum_{k=1}^{r} k \left( \frac{1}{k^s} - \frac{1}{ (k+1)^s } \right) = \sum_{k=1}^{r+1} \frac{1}{k^s}  \ - \    \frac{1}{ (r+1)^{s-1} }. \tag{6} $$
>
> Then using (6) in (3) we obtain 
>   $$ \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k^s} \ - \ \frac{1}{N^s} \leq s \int_1^b \frac{ [x] }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x \leq \sum_{k=1}^{N+1} \frac{1}{k^s} + 1 - \frac{2}{ (N+1)^s }.  \tag{7} $$
>   In (7) if we let $b \to \infty$, then $N \to \infty$ also, and then we obtain 
>   $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^s} \leq s \int_1^\infty \frac{ [x] }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x \leq 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^s}, $$
>   which is the same as 
>   $$\zeta(s) \leq s \int_1^\infty \frac{ [x] }{ x^{s+1} } \ \mathrm{d} x \leq 1 + \zeta(s). $$

Is what I've done so far the desired thing? If so, then what next?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud..I've seen many of your posts and i believe that your determined to solve the life out of Baby Rudin..:P I praise that..good for you...+1 from me.

Comment: @Marios Gretsas thanks. What proportions of the problems are required to be solved in a typical course taught using Rudin at an American or European university, I wonder?

Comment: I don't know because Baby Rudin is a book recomended to my university in Greece, especially for introductory courses in advance calculus of the 3rdand 4rth semester.But this book is not used as a teaching materia by the professors in my university in such early semesters and ages,because its quite a difficult book.

Comment: Most of the people i know use this book for self study and for its challenging exercises to gain more mathematical maturity and a concrete picture of  rigorus proofs

Answer (score 3):

$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-(n-1)) n^{-s} =
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n (n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}) \\= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \int_n^{n+1} s x^{-s-1}dx = s\int_1^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor x^{-s-1}dx$$

The name of this is "summation by parts" and "Abel summation formula"

Comment: how does the third equality in your answer occurs? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I really meant $\sum_{n\ge 1} (n-(n-1))n^{-s}=\sum_{n\ge 1} n \, n^{-s}-\sum_{n\ge 0} n \, (n+1)^{-s}$ at least for $\Re(s) > 2$. It is not hard to adapt it to $\Re(s) > 1$.

Comment: Oh, my bad.  Summation by parts is the last step... (it could've been that other step too, but yeah, that's overcomplicating)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt ? I don't follow you. Abel summation formula is $\sum_n n^{-s} = s \int_1^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor x^{-s-1}dx$, summation by parts is $\sum_n n^{-s} = \sum_n n(n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s})$

Comment: ._. I shall go get my coffee and try waking up a bit more.

Comment: Also look at [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) (and their Fourier transform) obtaining that $\zeta(s) = \int_{1-\epsilon}^\infty \Pi \text{I}(x) x^{-s}dx$. Integration by parts gives $= s \int_1^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor x^{-s-1}dx$. @SimplyBeautifulArt